# Getting form value

Tags: forms, input

I added this switch below to a form on my site but the value of the switch is not picking up on the thank you page. Any thoughts on why?

```
 <span class="switch-block">
        <label class="switch switch-green">
        <input id="finance" type="checkbox" class="switch-input">
        <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span>
        <span class="switch-handle"></span>
        </label>
        </span>
```

Value is supposed to pick up from finance ID.

Comment: You are missing "name" property of input field.As i know "name" property of input field is used to get the value from form.

Comment: `<input id="finance" name="finance" type="checkbox" class="switch-input">`

Comment: Yep. Wood for the trees. Thanks Bhushan!